# C# Unit Test to test attributes of properties of Dto

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, attributes, mocking

I have following Dto with some attributes to validate the properties. When I am passing some invalid values of properties, my unit test allows those values without validating as per the given condition of attributes. I am doing this first time so I have zero ideas to achieve it.

```
public class UserDto : IModelWithId
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [MinLength(1, ErrorMessageResourceName = "Error_User_UsernameMinLength", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Properties.Resources))]
    [MaxLength(255, ErrorMessageResourceName = "Error_User_UsernameMaxLength", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Properties.Resources))]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Za-z0-9äöüÄÖÜß]+(?:[._-][A-Za-z0-9äöüÄÖÜß]+)*$", ErrorMessageResourceName = "Error_User_UsernameFormat", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Properties.Resources))]
    public string UserName { get; set; }        

    [MinLength(1, ErrorMessageResourceName = "Error_User_NameMinLength", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Properties.Resources))]
    [MaxLength(255, ErrorMessageResourceName = "Error_User_NameMaxLength", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Properties.Resources))]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [MinLength(1, ErrorMessageResourceName = "Error_User_EmailMinLength", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Properties.Resources))]
    [MaxLength(255, ErrorMessageResourceName = "Error_User_EmailMaxLength", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Properties.Resources))]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Error_User_EmailAddress", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Properties.Resources))]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Where is your unit test code?

Comment: LordWilmore Hi, I am doing the unit test with mocking. I have tested various kinds of methods but not properties. So I don't have any code as I don't know, from where should I start.

Comment: @DipakAkhade Which framework is this code being used in? Most likely you will need to use what ever validation API is available in that framework.

Comment: @Nkosi I am using Entity Framework 6.0.

Comment: @DipakAkhade no. I am referring to whether this is a web project ie Asp.Net.* or desktop WPF..etc. Cannot tell that from information currently provided.

Comment: Its Web Application with AngularJS in frontend and MVC pattern with Entity Framework in the backend.

Comment: @DipakAkhade someone already provided a viable answer. You should check it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use validator class to validate your dto:

```
var dto = new UserDto();
dto.Email = "not an email";
var ctx = new System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationContext(dto);
// will throw an exception if invalid
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Validator.ValidateObject(dto, ctx, true);
```

or without exception like this:

```
var result = new List<ValidationResult>();
if (!Validator.TryValidateObject(dto, ctx, result)) {
    // inspect `result` list for specific validation errors
}
```